# Fail to Authenticate in mongo as localhost

Tags: mongodb, authentication

I use the latest mongo, and try to set the SuperUserAdmin as described in the Mongo Doc.

```
1) Start ./mongod --dbpath ../data    without auth
2) Run ./mongo
3) [mongo shell]: use admin
4) [mongo shell]: db.addUser( { user: "admin",
              pwd: "abcde1234",
              roles: [ "userAdminAnyDatabase" ] } )
5) [mongo shell]: db.shutdownServer()

then i restart mongod with auth:
6) ./mongod --auth --dbpath ../data
7) Run mongo (as localhost) again: ./mongo -u admin -p abcde1234

Then i get this error:
Javascript executiion failed: Error: 18 {code:18, ok:0.0, errmsg: 'auth fails'} at src/mongo/shell/db.js:L228
```

I tried different username &password, same thing..

what am i missing? I'm running on my Mac.

anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Role userAdminAnyDatabase allows for users administration only. This is why if new account has only this role, it can be authenticated only to database "admin", i.e. mongo -u admin -p abcde1234 localhost/admin should work.

You probably want to add role dbAdminAnyDatabase as well.

Comment: Even if dbAdminAnyDatabase is set , it doesn't work or at least it's still fails for test database as far as the methods described in the `create a user administrator`. But logs fine for admin database. Any one with a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
mongo admin -u admin -p abcde1234
```

otherwise you will connect to test database and admin can't.